# Restricting firebase records to authenticated user based on child property

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This may be a duplicate of [Firebase database rules. Allow when wildcard's child === auth.uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355348/firebase-database-rules-allow-when-wildcards-child-auth-uid), but I want to post an image here that shows my issue.

Why does this fail, what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I kind of doubt that the `user1` is the `auth.uid`

Comment: @theblindprophet It actually is, since that's what is specified in the authentication payload.

Comment: You have `@friend` in the rules, that should be `$friend`. For future questions don't post screenshots of text, post the actual text instead.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. Why not a screenshot? It succinctly captures the exact scenario. It should be familiar to all users of firebase. It is much more effort to copy and paste text.